# How do I add a "Use element instead of attribute" for vimeo videos using FancyBox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I wanted to know if it is possible to have the element instead instead of attribute effect work with a Vimeo group instead of images using Fancy Box App found here: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/.  I tried swapping the “fancybox" class in the HTML and the Javascript to "fancybox-media” but to no avail. I also changed the HTML a class to "fancybox-media”.

The Jfiddle link below if from the fancy box site on how to achieve the trick using images.  I am not even sure if this technique works with Vimeo Media. The goal is to have a button appear underneath the Vimeo video next to a title while it plays in the fancy box.

http://jsfiddle.net/cWNw9/

```
  $(".fancybox-media")
 .attr('rel', 'gallery')
.fancybox({
beforeLoad: function() {
    var el, id = $(this.element).data('title-id');
    if (id) {
        el = $('#' + id);

        if (el.length) {
            this.title = el.html();
        }
    }
}
});
```

Here is the HTML I tried:

```
<a class="fancybox-media" data-title-id="title-1” href="http://vimeo.com/36031564"><img      src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<div id="title-1" class="hidden">
This is 1st title. <a href="http://google.com">Some link</a>
</div>

<a class="fancybox" data-title-id="title-2"   href="http://vimeo.com/36031564"><img   src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>

<div id="title-2" class="hidden">
This is <b>2nd title</b>. <a href="http://google.com">Some link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When  you say

```
"Use element instead of attribute" for vimeo videos using FancyBox
```

I guess you are referring to fancybox [demo](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful) ==> No. 2, third example.

If so, the answer is yes. It's possible to use the same code as in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cWNw9/) of reference under the following considerations :

- you need to match the *class* attribute of all elements you want to bind to fancybox with the selector used in the fancybox initialization script like

  ```
  <a class="fancybox-media" href="{vimeo 1}" ...
  <a class="fancybox-media" href="{vimeo 2}" ...

  // matching selector
  $(".fancybox-media").fancybox()
  ```
- you also need to load the fancybox media helper, located in the helpers directory of the fancybox download like :

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{your path}/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
  ```
- intialize the fancybox media helper in your custom fancybox initialization script like :

  ```
  helpers: {
      media: {}
  }
  ```

Additionally, since you want to use a gallery of videos, you may not want the fancybox's navigation arrows to overlap the video container (and make the video controls inaccessible) so I would advice you to add the fancybox buttons helpers too. **Notice** that you also need to include the buttons helper js and css files.

So having included all the proper js and css files, you could use this code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox-media").attr('rel', 'gallery')
        .fancybox({
        beforeLoad: function () {
            var el, id = $(this.element).data('title-id');
            if (id) {
                el = $('#' + id);

                if (el.length) {
                    this.title = el.html();
                }
            }
        },
        // we are using button helpers so we don't need additional buttons
        modal: true, // disables default buttons
        helpers: {
            title: {
                type: 'inside' // optional
            },
            buttons: {}, // initialize buttons helper
            media: {} // initialize media helper
        }
    }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gJ66k/)**

Comment: Thank you so much Francisco!  You are amazing!   Thank you for taking the time to create a Jfiddle example as well as your descriptive response to make it much easier for me to understand.  Thank you again and have an amazing day!

You rock! :)